# finding index for min element in a row in numpy gives error elementwise == comparison failed

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I am trying to find the index corresponding to the minimum element in each row. My code looks like what's shown below:

```
dist=np.array([[0.15, 0.07, 0.14, 0.17, 0.15],
[0.16, 0.07, 0.14, 0.19, 0.15],
[0.10, 0.  , 0.10, 0.14, 0.09],
[0.07, 0.  , 0.06, 0.05, 0.14],
[0.10, 0.10, 0.  , 0.17, 0.06],
[0.08, 0.10, 0.07, 0.15, 0.03],
[0.05, 0.09, 0.06, 0.13, 0.  ],
[0.  , 0.10, 0.10, 0.07, 0.05],
[0.06, 0.14, 0.16, 0.02, 0.11],
[0.07, 0.14, 0.17, 0.  , 0.13]])
x= dist.min(axis=1)
print x
idx= np.where(dist==x)
print idx
print a[idx]
```

I get the following output

```
[0.07 0.07 0.   0.   0.   0.03 0.   0.   0.02 0.  ]
(array([], dtype=int64),)
[]
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:13: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  del sys.path[0]
```

For some reason the index value is empty and I also get a warning/error? Instead the indexes I would like to retrieve are (0,1), (1,1), (2,1) and so on corresponding to minimum element in each row.

Comment: `np.argmin(dist, axis=1)` returns the index of the min in each row. To tell you why a warning was raised you have to provide `b`. Numpy does not encourage comparison of arrays of different size, maybe that's why

Comment: b was a typo, I have fixed it with what I was using. np.argmin works. Also, I noticed that my method works for 1D array with no warning but does not work for 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.argmin` to find the indices:

```
min_indices = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)
min_tuples = [(row, col) for row, col in enumerate(min_indices)]
# outputs: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3])
# [(0, 1),
   (1, 1),
   (2, 1),
   (3, 1),
   (4, 2),
   (5, 4),
   (6, 4),
   (7, 0),
   (8, 3),
   (9, 3)]
```

FWIW, this information is accessible via `np.min??` in an `ipython` shell.